# how does one obtain motion in the theta and phi direction with motors?

Tags: motors

I'm not a mechanical engineer,but I'm guessing this is something that is well known by MEs. Say I have a rod and I want to move my pitch one direction, and my azimuth the other direction. How can I do this to get a full spherical direction capability for the rod? How many motors does it take, and  What is the correct placement of motors/gears? A picture or video might help.

Thanks.

Comment: You mean like the shoulder on a robotic arm? https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/proxy/Qe5YXjY5P9s1YDiQYyx6u8cZqk9a2WvruO1m_j2XOUWZOmFKMsNQ9GpGeZOpG3SC5R4o_pBmqWouhgGgr7D7990RlZPCs9ASAjmdK6M91Dz5YKkEJU_cd0Y6U567ySMQ9g1qVmbpRndf2QLdqTK5Hw

Comment: you need to be pointing to all points in a sphere AND you need to care about orientation?